# list values into entry widgets

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter-entry

I am trying to put list values into entry widgets, keep getting brackets and quotes.

```
lista = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
# These are normally strings, but can be integer
entrya = Entry(window, width=20)
entrya.insert(0, lista[0])
# This should put abc into entrya widget box, seems to put ['abc']
entrya.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
entryb = Entry(window, width=20)
entryb.insert(0, lista[1])
entryb.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3)
entryc = Entry(window, width=20)
entryc.insert(0, lista[2])
entryc.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6)
```

Comment: Possibly also include some image or description of output. This code seems to be working fine i.e. no quotes in label entries.

Comment: I tried this for one week, and never got it to work. Now, it works. fine. Sorry, for the waste of time. No, i did not update or change anything.